# PCoA function pcoa extract vectors; percentage of variance explained

Tags: r, variance, vegan, ape

I have a dataset consisting of 132 observations and 10 variables. 
These variables are all categorical. I am trying to see how my observations cluster and how they are different based on the percentage of variance. i.e I want to find out if a) there are any variables which helps to draw certain observation points apart from one another and b) if yes, what is the percentage of variance explained by it?

I was advised to run a PCoA (Principle Coordinates Analysis) on my data. I ran it using vegan and ape package. This is my code after loading my csv file into r, I call it data

```
#data.dis<-vegdist(data,method="gower",na.rm=TRUE)
#data.pcoa<-pcoa(data.dis)
```

I was then told to extract the vectors from the pcoa data and so

```
#data.pcoa$vectors
```

It then returned me 132 rows but 20 columns of values (e.g. from Axis 1 to Axis 20)

I was perplexed over why there were 20 columns of values when I only have 10 variables. I was under the impression that I would only get 10 columns. If any kind souls out there could help to explain a) what do the vectors actually represent and b) how do I get the percentage of variance explained by Axis 1 and 2?

Another question that I had was I don't really understand the purpose of extracting the eigenvalues from `data.pcoa` because I saw some websites doing that after running a pcoa on their distance matrix but there was no further explanation on it.

Answer (score 4):

Gower index is non-Euclidean and you can expect more real axes than the number of variables in Euclidean ordination (PCoA). However, you said that your variables are categorical. I assume that in **R** lingo they are factors. If so, you should *not* use `vegan::vegdist()` which only accepts numeric data. Moreover, if the variable is defined as a factor, `vegan::vegdist()` refuses to compute the dissimilarities and gives an error. If you managed to use `vegdist()`, you did not properly define your variables as factors. If you really have factor variables, you should use some other package than **vegan** for Gower dissimilarity (there are many alternatives).

Te percentage of "variance" is a bit tricky for non-Euclidean dissimilarities which also give some negative eigenvalues corresponding to imaginary dimensions. In that case, the sum of all positive eigenvalues (real axes) is higher than the total "variance" of data. `ape::pcoa()` returns the information you asked in the element `values`. The proportion of variances explained is in its element `values$Relative_eig`. The total "variance" is returned in element `trace`. All this was documented in `?pcoa` where I read it.